# Need guidance in re-writing this query

Tags: sql, performance, hive, query-optimization, hiveql

We have this query which we run to generate the calendar week data 
this query hits the same view twice. and perhaps creates a cartesian product due to absence of a join ON clause.

Is there anyway to re-write this query optimally.

```
SELECT cal_date,
       regexp_replace(cal_date, '-', '') AS PC_cal_date,
       year_num*100+week_num AS year_week_num,
       CASE
           WHEN year_num*100+pd_num IN (min_year_pd_num, max_year_pd_num) THEN 'A'
           ELSE 'B'
       END AS yr_pd_ind,
       year_num*100+pd_num AS yr_pd_num,
       dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY year_num*100+week_num DESC) AS wk_index,
                         dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY year_num*100+pd_num DESC) AS pd_index
FROM mstr_v.local_cal_date t1,

  (SELECT max(year_num*100+pd_num) max_year_pd_num,
          min(year_num*100+pd_num) min_year_pd_num
   FROM mstr_v.local_cal_date
   WHERE cal_date IN (date(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, cast(date_format(CURRENT_DATE, 'u') AS int)+105*7+1)),
                      date(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, cast(date_format(CURRENT_DATE, 'u') AS int)))) ) t2
WHERE cal_date BETWEEN date(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, cast(date_format(CURRENT_DATE, 'u') AS int)+105*7)) 
AND date(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, cast(date_format(CURRENT_DATE, 'u') AS int)+1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns calculated in t2 subquery can be calculated without second table scan (in the same subquery) if you move where clause which is currently inside the t2 into case statements and calculate min and max with over():

```
SELECT cal_date,
       regexp_replace(cal_date, '-', '') AS PC_cal_date,
       year_num*100+week_num AS year_week_num,
       CASE
           WHEN year_num*100+pd_num IN (min_year_pd_num, max_year_pd_num) THEN 'A'
           ELSE 'B'
       END AS yr_pd_ind,
       year_num*100+pd_num AS yr_pd_num,
       dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY year_num*100+week_num DESC) AS wk_index,
                         dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY year_num*100+pd_num DESC) AS pd_index
FROM (select t1.*,            
             max(case when cal_date IN (date(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, cast(date_format(CURRENT_DATE, 'u') AS int)+105*7+1)),
                                        date(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, cast(date_format(CURRENT_DATE, 'u') AS int))))        
                      then  year_num*100+pd_num end) over() as max_year_pd_num,
             min(case when cal_date IN (date(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, cast(date_format(CURRENT_DATE, 'u') AS int)+105*7+1)),
                                        date(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, cast(date_format(CURRENT_DATE, 'u') AS int)))) 
                      then year_num*100+pd_num end) over() as min_year_pd_num
      from mstr_v.local_cal_date t1
)t1
WHERE cal_date BETWEEN date(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, cast(date_format(CURRENT_DATE, 'u') AS int)+105*7)) 
AND date(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, cast(date_format(CURRENT_DATE, 'u') AS int)+1))
```